# {% load static %} what does this snippet achieve?

Tags: django

Dears, I was learning the Django official tutorial. In the entire process, I did not create a custom tag set called "static". What does load static achieve here?

According to Django docs, load plays this following role.

```
load

Loads a custom template tag set.

For example, the following template would load all the tags and filters registered in somelibrary and otherlibrary located in package package:
```

Comment: It loads the set of template tags define in the static app into the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,thanks for answering. I have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' this app installed.  Does the "static " refer to this app?

Comment: indeed, this is mentioned in the documentation on `static`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you! I just found out that in the old version the expression was "load staticfiles''. It was more clear.

Answer (score 1):

when you wont to add CSS, javascript, HTML or etc to our python project, you need to make a folder on root direction and called **assets**.

after this, in setting.py you need to add some words to Django knows where you store your files(CSS,js, HTML)

and finally, you must add this tag `{% load static % }` in your HTML files, to when you load HTML files, static files load with this.

I create a simple Django project, to show you how you could use them.

this project on my GitHub right now called: Django/ First app

please check this link : [Github - First App - Templates](https://github.com/Mratashnejad/django_first_app_templates/tree/master/first_app/first_app)

if is helpful, please take a vote. thanx